# Stealth action with PHP in POST Submit

Tags: php, post, submit, action

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

have here some solution to make a stealth action during this submit? before submit the action. Thanks for every tip.

About stealth action i'm about 1 submit on 2 actions. In php without JavaScripts.

IF we can't make 2 actions on 1 submit, we can use case.

by default is started default case where we submit our post, with value of case2
after it page is reloaded with case2, here we use vars from first post, and is needed to submit it automaticaly

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you're actually trying to do, or it will wind up closed. It is not answerable in its current form because "stealth action" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Your updated description of "stealth action" still doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can capture the form's submit event and add your code prior to the request being sent to the server. First, you should give your form an id, like this:

```
<form action="..." id="cool-form">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you can attach an event handler based on the id. I'd recomment using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), where you can attach the event like this:

```
$('#cool-form').submit(function(ev) {
    /* put your custom action here */
});
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch, very good answer, but i need clean php solution(

Comment: You probably can't do it with only php since it only gets called once the post is already posted, which means php will be invoked to late to be able to do the "stealth action"

Comment: i can to submit first form and use the post, also to create second form after submit, and to input vars from first form, but how to submit the second form automaticaly? something like <script type='text/javascript'>document.myForm.submit();</script> but with php(( thanks.